# Setting up git repository with local environment [e.g. virtual environment]

Tags: git

I have a directory containing files of a git repository along-with some lib and bin files file. But there is no versioning system in the folder(no .git folder).

How do I setup git repository for my local use, which is in sync with remote git repository along with bin-files which already exist in local folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a new git repository by typing `git init` within your working directory.

This will create the `.git` directory. Then you need to tell git where the remote is, so go to github.com and create a new repository.

When you create it go to your working directory and type:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

and replace user and repo with the appropriate fields.

The first thing you ll have to do is create your initial commit. Typically the initial commit is the README file:

```
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master
```

After you do that, your README file should appear on github.com under the repository you created.

The next step is push your current bin-files to remote. Assuming you want to track all of the files in your working directory do this:

`git add .` which will add all of your files in version control.

Then commit your changes `git commit -m "Your commit message"` and push them to the remote `git push origin master`.